# I'm developing the website in wordpress and I want to change the active state in main menu of my website, but I'm stuck

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using HTML5 Blank custom post.

Below is the wordpress code for menu.

`wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'primary',
                  'container_class'=>'Top Nav' ,
                  'container_id'=> 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                  'menu_class'=> 'nav navbar-nav text-uppercase nav-menu'));`

I'm not getting where to add css properties to make changes to the menu.
I just simply want to change active state of menu links. Like when someone visits the about us page. The about us link text remains white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target with CSS these classes: "**current-menu-item**" or "**current_page_item**".

And if it's a parent page "*current-page-ancestor*".